# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [] on this ManagedType []

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

So i have this kotlin project:

```
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.*

@MappedSuperclass
abstract class ContainerEntity<TData : DataEntity> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int = 0

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], optional = false)
    lateinit var data: TData
}


@MappedSuperclass
abstract class DataEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int = 0

    val created = Date()
}

@Entity
class Car : ContainerEntity<CarData>()

@Entity
class CarData : DataEntity() {
    var color = "red"
}

@Entity
class Apple : ContainerEntity<AppleData>()

@Entity
class AppleData : DataEntity() {
    var age = 32
}

/**
 * WORKS
 */

interface CarRepository : CrudRepository<Car, Int> {
    fun findByDataColor(color: String): Car?
}


/**
 * FAILS
 */

interface AppleRepository : CrudRepository<Apple, Int> {
    fun findByDataAge(age: Int): Apple?
}
```

Getting this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [age] on this ManagedType [com.example.demo.DataEntity]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath.locateAttributeInternal(SingularAttributePath.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:673) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:606) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:578) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.getTypedPath(JpaQueryCreator.java:381) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:304) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:209) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:122) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:57) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:119) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:147) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:270) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        ... 98 common frames omitted
```

There is small demo project: https://github.com/TomGrill/spring-hibernate-bug

As requested:

```
//@MappedSuperclass
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
abstract class ContainerEntity<TData : DataEntity> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int = 0

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], optional = false)
    lateinit var data: TData
}


//@MappedSuperclass
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
abstract class DataEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int = 0

    val created = Date()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@MappedSuperclass` with `DataEntity` but you should use `@Inheritance`.

`@MappedSuperclas`s is the annotation to tell JPA that all subclasses must have the inherited attributes but it has nothing to do with JPA inheritance.

To use inheritance with JPA you have to use `@Inheritance`.

There are three strategies that define how to store the intheritance tree to the database: SINGLE_TABLE, JOINED and TABLE_PER_CLASS.

- SINGLE_TABLE (default): All classes on the same table
- JOINED: Table per class even if they are abstract
- TABLE_PER_CLASS: Only tables for non-abstract classes

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error with all combinations

Comment: Thanks, I updated the OP. I tried all 3 `InheritanceTypes`

Comment: I'm afraid you have one level to much of Generics. Because Generics are a compile time construct Spring Data does not know which type you have during runtime. What's the purpose of ContainerEntity and DataEntity? It feels overcomplicated

Comment: Alright, I am basically looking for a way to have a rollback mechanism. So the container would have 1 data record assigned which is the active one. So i can update data record and set is as active or pick an old one and set to active. Probably not the best approach I took there. I did this without generics in an older project. My plan was to make it reusable. Probably there is a better approach to handle this. Currently I think having a custom Repository is the solution.